# Optimizing A LINQ To Objects Query

Tags: c#, .net, performance, linq, optimization

I'm trying to optimize the below LINQ query to improve it's speed performance.  The number of objects it's searching against could be in the tens of thousands.

```
var lQuery = from o in oEvents
where (o.oSalesEvent != null && o.oSalesEvent.OccurDate < oCalcMgr.OccurDate && (
                (oCalcMgr.InclTransTypes == Definitions.TransactionTypes.SalesAll) ?
                   (o.oSalesEvent.EventStateID == ApprovedID || o.oSalesEvent.EventStateID == PendingID) : 
                   o.oSalesEvent.EventStateID == ApprovedID)) &&
      ((oCalcMgr.InclTransTypes == Definitions.TransactionTypes.SalesAll) ? 
                (o.oSalesMan.oEmployment.EventStateID == ApprovedID || o.oSalesMan.oEmployment.EventStateID == PendingID) : 
                 o.oSalesMan.oEmployment.EventStateID == ApprovedID)
select new { SaleAmount = o.SaleAmount.GetValueOrDefault(), CompanyID = o.oSalesEvent.CompanyID };
```

The query basically says, give me the sales amounts and company ids from all sale events that occurred prior to a certain date.  The sale event's status and the salesman's employment status should either always be "approved" or they can be also "pending" if specified.

As you can see there's a date comparison and a couple of integer comparisons.  Which integer comparison used is based on whether or not a property matches a certain Enum value.

I have some ideas of my own on ways to go about the optimization, but I want to hear others thoughts, who might have more insight into how LINQ would translate this query behind the scenes.

Thanks

Comment: Before making something faster you need to first understand why it's not fast enough now.  I don't see any kind of performance analysis in your question and that makes it impossible to answer this question.  What is **slow** about this query that needs fixing?  If you can't answer that then how do you know if any of the answers are faster?

Comment: It looks like the second half of your `where` clause is independent of `o` and thus could be pulled out of the query.

Comment: Exactly. What is `ied`? And really, what is with all those `o`s in your names?

Comment: Instead of optimizing the performance i would start with optimizing the readability. Create methods which encapsulate complexity to avoid such horrible quries. Nobody will understand what you are doing there at first view.

Comment: @Rawling and Daniel Hilgarth...Sorry...copy and paste error.  I changed the name ied to o just to ask the question.  Fixed it in the answer above.

Comment: @TimSchmelter  Thanks, but not the point of the question.  I know readability can be improved through different means.  I'm focusing on speed currently as I want it to perform faster.

Comment: You might want to adjust your readability for _users on SO_ so we might be more compelled to answer your question.  The bonus being afterwards you'll have more readable source for you and anyone else who needs to maintain it.

Comment: @JaredPar I've run my application through a Performance analyzer and notice that a lot of time is spent in this query, so I'm trying to optimize it.  It's not surprising due to the large number of objects, but these are all just simple properties, with no additional calcs, so I want to see what other methods of optimization might be available to me by LINQ to assist.

Comment: @Nullqwerty but what part of this query is causing the problems? If it shows time in this query it should also show the sub-operation that is taking the most time.  If nothing stands out then possible the problem is the frequency with which you are executing an already optimized query.

Comment: @xanadont I just edited it and added in some line breaks to try and help out.  I also adjusted variable names when originally posted for the same reason.

Comment: @JaredPar Integer, Enum, and Date comparisons are all fairly simple operations, so I don't believe those to be the causes. LINQ has to query tens of thousands of objects to find the result set, so the answer lies in trying to make that as easy and quick as possible for LINQ to do so.  And maybe the answer is, it's already optimized and there's nothing else LINQ can do. That's fine if so. But there could be other answers like "First do an orderby on the dates as LINQ will have an easier time traversing" or "break it up into 2 queries", etc. I'm just looking for additional ideas.

Comment: @JaredPar Forgot to mention on the second part of your question.  Unfortunately the performance profiler I'm using doesn't break out linq queries into sub parts and show execution time of each.  But it's all just staring int, date, and enum comparisons, so I'm not expecting something too revealing there.

Comment: Start out by verifying that you have a problem.  How long does the query take to execute?  What speeds does it need to execute in for you to meet your requirements?  Are you just a few percent too slow, are you currently fast enough but just want it to be faster because you expect the data to grow, or are you already fast enough and just looking for more?  As others have said, this doesn't seem like an expensive query.  My guess is that the source data uses deferred execution and that source data is being evaluated here, which is what is taking up so much of the time.

Comment: Are `oSalesMan` and `oEmployment` lazy loaded?

Comment: To build on what Servy just said, try putting `var oEventsList = oEvents.ToList();` right before this query, and then selecting on `oEventsList` instead.  See if that isolates the issue or not.

Comment: @Bobson, oEvents is of type List<Event>.  Probably should have mentioned that.  Thanks though.

Comment: @Magnus.  They are not.  Thanks though.  They're all preloaded and strongly typed.

Comment: Is the data fetched using Linq2SQL or Linq2Entities? (To rule out any lazy loading and deferred execution)

Comment: @Servy  Problem has been verified.  It can take up to 1 second to run.  It may not be an actual "issue", but rather just due to the large number of objects in oEvents.  I want it faster because if it's called 3 times sequentially (using three different sets of oEvents objects) that could be 3 seconds the user waits.  The properties and are objects are all preloaded by the time it gets here. My current methods for optimization rely around trying to reduce the result set by breaking up oEvents into multiple objects, but my reason for coming hear is to see if there's any LINQ optimizations.

Comment: Oh well...Thanks everyone.  I was just making sure there wasn't something blatantly obvious I wasn't aware of with LINQ.  Like "Always do xyz type of query in these situations, instead of what you have, as LINQ can optimize it the other way.  Guess not.  I'll focus on optimizing it through other methods rather than focusing on the LINQ aspect.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: If you are doing in-memory queries with LINQ I would expect you should filter as many items as possible as soon as possible, hence start with the filters that removes the most items (if possible at compiletime).

Comment: Did you put the most selective criteria in front? (I.e. the ones that evaluate to false most often). That would cause the other comparisons to run the least possible number of times.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that your biggest challenge is that you're doing multiple criteria checks in your Linq statement that will take alot of time.
What about creating a new property in oEvents - Say "IsEligable" and set it's value within the Set statements of your other variables (much faster than constant re-querying of each variable in the Linq).

Then, by the time you get to this part of your code, you could update your Linq to be something along the lines of:

```
var lQuery = from o in oEvents
where (o.oSalesEvent != null && o.oSalesEvent.OccurDate < oCalcMgr.OccurDate && o.IsEligable == True)
select new { SaleAmount = o.SaleAmount.GetValueOrDefault(), CompanyID = o.oSalesEvent.CompanyID };
```

... I'm guessing that would speed up the execution, but just a thought...

Comment: Hi John,  Thanks for the answer.  I agree, caching the statuses would be a performance improvement.  Unfortunately, if I created the IsEligible property, I would have to make it be a dynamic property that would do the check on the fly.  This is because the statuses can change during run time.  Once I make it by dynamic, it's essentially the same as original since the re-querying is still occurring.  I appreciate the help though!

Answer (score 0):

This is as much to improve readability as to possibly speed it up, but give this a try:

```
var lQueryTemp = from o in oEvents
where (o.oSalesEvent != null && o.oSalesEvent.OccurDate < oCalcMgr.OccurDate)

if (oCalcMgr.InclTransTypes == Definitions.TransactionTypes.SalesAll)
{
  lQueryTemp = from o in lQueryTemp
        where (o.oSalesEvent.EventStateID == ApprovedID || o.oSalesEvent.EventStateID == PendingID) &&
      (o.oSalesMan.oEmployment.EventStateID == ApprovedID || o.oSalesMan.oEmployment.EventStateID == PendingID);
}
else
{
  lQueryTemp = from o in lQueryTemp
        where (o.oSalesEvent.EventStateID == ApprovedID &&  o.oSalesMan.oEmployment.EventStateID == ApprovedID);
}

var lQuery = from o in lQueryTemp
select new { SaleAmount = o.SaleAmount.GetValueOrDefault(), CompanyID = o.oSalesEvent.CompanyID };
```

This might speed it up by pulling out both checks of `oCalcMgr.InclTransTypes`, which is effectively a constant for purposes of this query.

Comment: Thanks Bobson.  I originally started out with something not too dissimilar.  I then started experimenting with bringing it into one LINQ query in the hopes that maybe there would be fewer loops that way.  My original code did have some differences to yours though, so I implemented it as you have.  I ran it 5 times both ways.  Unfortunately, Execution speed is actually slightly slower this way (on average .21 seconds slower).  Very small difference, but didn't work out nonetheless.  Thanks anyway though!